# Dotnet ef database update command failed

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following error when I execute ***dotnet ef database update*** command

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
one
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnectionDependencies Microsoft.EntityFrameworkC   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateReadOnlyConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnectionDependencies Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnectionDependencies.With(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptions)'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which package versions are you using? I was getting this error, and could fix by downgrade my EF packages to stabilized versions (not previews or betas).